# The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: web-services, http-status-code-401, .net-3.5

I have a .NET 2.0 website (VB) running in my IIS6 (XP Pro SP2) and a .NET 3.5 (configured as .NET2 under IIS's ASP.NET tab, of course) hosting an ASMX web service.

In Chrome, I can call the ASMX and invoke the web methods successfully. However, in calling the web methods in code, from the .NET 2.0 website I get:

> ***The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.***

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to set the credentials in you application when you initialise the `webService` object.

Something like `webService.UseDefaultCredentials = true`

This will set the credentials of the request to the current user executing the application.

Comment: This is for the cient created in VB/C# .. what about Java, say I need to connect to this webservice through mobile application. In that case, I can't get the Default credentials.

Comment: you saved lot of time. Thank you.

Comment: Oh my God.  We've had code in our ASP.Net site without this "UseDefaultCredentials" setting for years, and it's always worked fine.  Yesterday, a Microsoft security patch was applied suddenly we got a "401 Unauthorized" error each time.  Adding this one line of code fixed the problem...  really strange.

Comment: This will probably work when developing the application. However, be careful when deploying it as you may not have the authentication being made in the deployment machine, in which case you'll need to set them as mentioned in [Mohamad Chami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38615047/214639).

Answer (score 4):

**you can use this:**

```
webservice.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

**if does not work, use the below code instead of the code above**

```
webservice.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password", "domain");
webservice.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

**note: the username Password and domain is the user credential of the user that access to webservice**

so make sure that user have permission to access to web service

maybe the user is the windows user

and you can get the domain from: right click in "MyComputer" and properties
the domain is the Computer name or Workgroup

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I had the same issue and your solution worked for me thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In IIS 7, enable anonymous authentication and you should be able to debug.

Answer (score 3):

```
webService.UseDefaultCredentials = true
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

im am test this way:

```
CheckListService.CheckList chkSrvice = new CheckListService.CheckList() {
    UseDefaultCredentials = true };
```