# Open Azure VM to Internet for a web site

Tags: http, azure, azure-virtual-network

I am new in Azure. I want to open IIS to external access. My VM is WS 2012 R2, and all is configured by default.

The only access I get from internet is RDP, which I use for admin.
I tried both FTP and HTTP, but none works to find my server from outside. Same for nslookup.

If I do an RDP connexion on sp16fu12.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com, it succeeds.
If I try http://mymachine.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com, it fails.

I have added inbound and outbound security rules for protocols http and ftp on my network security group.
DNS is default Azure DNS.
What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, please ensure you had open ports(FTP and HTTP) on Azure network security group and Windows Firewall.

1.Open Ports on Azure network security group(NSG Inbound rules).More information about NSG please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal#quick-commands).

Notes:Azure NSG could associate on NIC and subnet. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal#associate-the-nsg-to-the-frontend-subnet).

2.Open ports on Firewall. More information about open ports on Windows Firewall please refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345310(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks.
I have opened firewall, both in Windows (inside VM) and in Azure portal (outside).
The answer is allways that the URL adress is unknown, server cannot be accessed, page cannot be reached, etc...

Comment: Do you mean you try to `RDP http://mymachine.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com ` It is not possible, you only could rdp IP or DNSName.

Comment: 2. RDP is ok , with my URL, but it is the only protocol that works.

Comment: No problem to access to my web pages, and ftp folders, Inside my Azure network.
NEW point : I built a new site in IIS, published ont port 81 instead of 80, and that works. What can be the difference ?

Comment: @JFF42 According to your description, you problem seems a firewall issue.

Comment: Hi. Now I found my sites, but get error "401 Unauthorized".
- what has changed may be due to several reboots, to take advice of my rules ??

Comment: @JFF42 It seems your web configure issue. Maybe you could refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282780/the-request-failed-with-http-status-401-unauthorized)

Comment: Thanks. I think I must follow on another forum category, as the second part of the problem is not bound to Azure.